# Submitting Multiple Records via AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

General question here - I have a basic HTML table with editable table cells. I want to keep a tally of each record that is edited by a user and then *sent* via an AJAX post.

I've seen one method handle this by adding a **flag** to each table row (`<tr>`). The flag is changed from 'N' to 'Y' when the row is edited, then a separate method which iterates through the table to search for each 'Y' flag on form submission. However I'm looking for other possible solutions.

[image]

When selecting the **Save** button I have yet to make, Records 4 & 6 will be sent to the AJAX post.

Anyone tackled something similar to this?

Comment: How about storing initial values on a JS variable and checking them against the current values when save is pressed?

Comment: You may need to select values from those input fields of which attribute is set to 'changed' or something. Once posted and returns 200 OK, you remove the 'changed' flag from those inputs. Does this help?